# simple calculator function return 0 instead of the operation (e.g. mass * acceleration)

Tags: python-2.7

```
userchoice = raw_input('What do you want to calculate?\nmass, acceleration or force')

def calculator():
    if userchoice == 'mass':
        acceleration = int(raw_input('What will be the acceleration?'))
        force = int(raw_input('And what it will be the force?'))
        return force / acceleration

    elif userchoice == 'force':
        acceleration = int(raw_input('What will be the acceleration?'))
        mass = int(raw_input('And what it will be the mass?'))
        return mass * acceleration

    elif userchoice == 'acceleration':
        force = int(raw_input('And what it will be the force?'))
        mass = int(raw_input('And what it will be the mass?'))
        return force/mass

    else:
        return "You didn't choose any of the available options"


print calculator()
```

After I'm running any of the flows I'm getting 0 as a result instead of the operation.
Taken the following flow: User chose mass, he inputs a acceleration of 20 and a force of 2. The results should be 10, but I'm getting 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of division are by default casted to int. Use `float()` methods as below:

```
userchoice = raw_input('What do you want to calculate?\nmass, acceleration or force')

def calculator():
    if userchoice == 'mass':
        acceleration = int(raw_input('What will be the acceleration?'))
        force = int(raw_input('And what it will be the force?'))
        return float(force) / float(acceleration)

    elif userchoice == 'force':
        acceleration = int(raw_input('What will be the acceleration?'))
        mass = int(raw_input('And what it will be the mass?'))
        return float(mass) * float(acceleration)

    elif userchoice == 'acceleration':
        force = int(raw_input('And what it will be the force?'))
        mass = int(raw_input('And what it will be the mass?'))
        return float(force)/float(mass)

    else:
        return "You didn't choose any of the available options"


print calculator()
```

And it will works fine:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
>>> 
What do you want to calculate?
mass, acceleration or forcemass
What will be the acceleration?3
And what it will be the force?5
1.66666666667
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue... I thought when I'm giving the acceleration 20 and the force 2, I should get 10 since the operation would be acceleration/force, but it's actually force/acceleration ...